# 'ng test' throwing webpack error, Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-5

Problem: running 'ng test' throws an error, '**webpack_require**(...).context is not a function'

Problem in detail: I am using cypress also, for this test i dont want to use that. expect() method was having conflicts between angular testing and cypress, so i have imported expect from @jest/globals.

```
import { expect } from '@jest/globals';
```

Test.ts finds tests like this,

```
const context = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
```

Versions:

Webpack: 5.75.0
Angular cli: 15.0.4
typescript: 4.8.2

Logs:

```
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
  TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
      at Module.4289 (  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test.ts:27:25)
      at __webpack_require__ (  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at __webpack_exec__ (  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:11661:48)
      at   localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:11662:54
      at Function.__webpack_require__.O 
( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/chunk loaded:23:1)
      at  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:11663:56
      at webpackJsonpCallback ( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/jsonp chunk loading:71:1)
      at  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:1:59
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Uncaught TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
  TypeError: __webpack_require__(...).context is not a function
      at Module.4289 ( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/test.ts:27:25)
      at __webpack_require__ ( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/bootstrap:19:1)
      at __webpack_exec__ ( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:11661:48)
      at  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:11662:54
      at Function.__webpack_require__.O ( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/chunk loaded:23:1)
      at  localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/main.js:11663:56
      at webpackJsonpCallback ( localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/webpack/runtime/jsonp chunk loading:71:1)
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)
^C02 02 2023 15:08:45.447:WARN [Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64)]: Disconnected (0 times) Cl
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.005 secs / 0 secs)
Chrome 109.0.0.0 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  Disconnected Client disconnected from CONNECTED state (transport close)
```

I tried changing it to index.js

```
const components = require.context('./', true, /^index.js$/)
```

also tried adding below code to angular.json

```
"polyfills": ["zone.js", "zone.js/testing"],
```

Expected Behaviour : Should not throw error, and run tests from all spec.ts files.

Edit:

Removing

```
const components = require.context('./', true, /^index.js$/)
context.keys().map(context);
```

from test.ts works, and all tests are executed, i couldn't find the path from where it is getting all .spec.ts files.